# Azure Devops -job defined in first stage executing in all stages

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm learning Azure DevOps Pipelines, and I have a scenario where the job defined in the first stage is being executed in all stages, despite only being defined in the first stage.This is not the behaviour I want, but as I'm new to this, it may actually be the expected behaviour. Can you have a look at the yaml below and adivse? The task task: Maven@3.205.1 executes at each stages. Thanks

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

stages:
- stage: stage1
  jobs:
  - job: myJob
    steps:
    - task: Maven@3.205.1
      inputs:
        mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
        mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
        javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
        jdkVersionOption: '11'
        jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
        publishJUnitResults: true
        testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
        goals: 'clean install'

- stage: stage2
  jobs:
  - job: mySecondJob
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      displayName: Node install
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '6.x' # The version we're installing
        # Write the installed version to the command line
    - script: which node

- stage: stage3
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - script: exit 0

  - job: B
    dependsOn: A
    condition: failed()
    steps:
    - script: echo this will run when A fails

  - job: C
    dependsOn:
    - A
    - B
    condition: succeeded('B')
    steps:
    - script: echo this will run when B runs and succeeds
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description and concern, if you want to set the task: Maven@3.205.1 executes at each stages, it is needed to set the specified task at each Stage, not only in the first stage.

So, it is suggested that you could use YAML template and here is the document: [Templates - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) for your reference. From the document, you could get to know how to set each stage to call the same template.